# Ansible playbook does not run tasks from roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I try to write a small ansible-playbook for basic setup of a server, but my tasks from roles refuse to run :))

Playbook has this directory structure:

```
└── install
├── group_vars
│   └── all.yml
├── roles
│   ├── basic_setup
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   └── user_management
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
└── setup.yml
```

setup.yml looks like:

```
---

- hosts: '{{ target }}'
  become: yes
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - { role: basic_setup }
    - { role: user_management }
```

And, for example, my `install/roles/basic_setup/tasks/main.yml` looks like:

```
---

- name: Install python2.7
  raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- name: 'test this playbook'
  shell: "echo 'hello world'"
```

When I try to run playbook i get this output:

```
    $ ansible-playbook install/setup.yml --ask-pass --user=root --extra-vars "target=192.168.1.228" -vvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
 _____________________
< PLAYBOOK: setup.yml >
 ---------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

1 plays in install/setup.yml
 ____________
< PLAY RECAP >
 ------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

File `install/roles/user_management/tasks/main.ym`l looks like this:

```
---

- name: Ensure bogdan user
  user:
    name: admin
    state: present

- name: Ensure ssh key access
  authorized_key:
    key: "{{ lookup('file', key_path) }}"
    user: admin
    state: present

- name: Ensure admin user user is sudoer
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/sudoers
    line: "admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
    regexp: '^admin ALL\='
    state: present
    validate: "visudo -cf %s"

- name: Create deployer user
  user:
    name: deployer
    state: present

- name: Ensure ssh key access
  authorized_key:
    key: "{{ lookup('file', key_path) }}"
    user: deployer
    state: present
```

Can someone help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please disable cowsay (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-disable-cowsay).

Comment: @techraf, nothing is happening on the remote server. And locally no output in present. Ansible does not output how many tasks run, how many rasks failed, etc...

Comment: @el_wichtel, the output without cowsay:
`$ ansible-playbook install/setup.yml --ask-pass --extra-vars "target=192.168.1.228" -vvvvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc

PLAYBOOK: setup.yml ************************************************************
1 plays in install/setup.yml

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************`

Comment: @techraf, sorry, I forgot to post my "user_management" main.yml file. I updated now my question. Also, on remote server i expect this playbook to create that 2 users ans assign ssh keys. I am pretty noob using Ansible... I am learning how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your playbook is fine. Problem is in your command and inventory file.

I have never seen it work with specifying an IP address for **hosts:** field.

Technically, what you're currently doing is:

```
- hosts: '{{ target }}' # 192.168.1.228, comes from command line variable
  become: yes
  remote_user: root
```

What you should be doing is have an inventory file (inventory.ini) that maps an ip address to a name, syntax like this:

```
[your_host]
192.168.1.228
```

The playbook stays the same, but on command line you do:

```
$ ansible-playbook install/setup.yml --ask-pass --user=root --extra-vars "target=your_host" -vvv
```

Which will work.
It will also work with using the hostname. (Full hostname in --extra-vars)

I am not sure why they have the IP address example in docs.